# Why lua and not python?

Tags: python, lua

I mean instead of lualatex. I came across the [python package](http://www.texample.net/weblog/2008/oct/24/embedding-python-latex/), so I am not asking about python support.

What was so special about lua that people spent so much time on that instead of doing something with python (and which would be arguably be more useful)?

Comment: http://luatex.org/faq.html Edit: By the way, see also http://ctan.org/pkg/pythontex

Comment: This has been answered several times by the LuaTeX team, and I'm not sure it really fits well here (perhaps open-ended). Example issues: Python is _big_ in comparison to Lua (self-contained LuaTeX binary on my system ~7 Mb, Python installation 134 Mb!).

Comment: http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaVersusPython